# Removing GB from PC Windows 7

Tags: local-storage

My PC says that it has 29.2 GB free of 59.5 GB. How do I remove say, 10GB? I go to my IOBit uninstaller, but I've removed everything that's a GB or more or 500 MB's.

How do I free 10 GBs?

Comment: I can only gain ~500MB from Disk Cleanup

Comment: Well, the most logical way would be get a external hard drive so you can transfer all of your large files to it. It will be easy to access. Otherwise you would use some kind of online file storage service, which costs money. (you can't just free GB's of space without removing files.)

Comment: Looking for an easy, at home solution

Comment: Have you seen where the  disk space is being used by using a utility such as [TreeSize Free : Quickly Scan Directory Sizes and Find Space Hogs](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/)?

Comment: You could try compressing large files that you are not using, but you won;t free up much space. Your only at home solution would be to delete multimedia files. You can get a cheap external hard drive and move all large files there. That is your best option, online you can find them costing under $50.

Comment: No monies shall be spent in pursuit of the solution to this problem

Comment: Its OK To delete things like Program Files, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clean the Temp folders , and make sure you clean up the Recycle bin also.

Also , if your machine is accessing by multiple users , there profiles also consume some amount of space , their desktop might contains the big file available.

Comment: I try to delete Restore Points -- but it is not working as intended

Comment: Are you getting any error ? What is the chellange you are getting ?